# Can you record a video with expo-camera while running TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow.js

There is a bug with react-native Tensor Flow while expo-camera is recording so that Tensor Flow does not get new image data to process or render to the screen.

I am using the Tensor Flow PoseModel to track the user's pose. When I turn on recording with expo-camera, Tensor Flow no longer receives an updated image tensor so the screen looks stuck.

I think there is a problem with getting the correct WebGL texture from expo-camera while the camera is recording. But I am new to both Tensor Flow and WebGL so I haven't figured out the issue.

[YouTube Video That Shows Bug](https://youtu.be/xg0Ln2GWYJI)

This repo gives a minimal reproduction: https://github.com/vpontis/expo-camera-tensor-flow-bug